# Popup doesn't show

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

I'm using [jquery popup overlay](http://vast-eng.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/) plugin (I've chose it because it's responsive). And I have on my page many links which when I'll click on them It'll show a popup with different content..

here's my code :

```
<div class="more">
    <a class="my_modal_open_1" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div id="my_modal_1">
    <div class="image-odd">
        <img src="images/post/1_guerlain.png" width="421" height="590" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="my_modal-close">Close</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".my_modal_open_1").click(function() {
        $("#my_modal_1").popup();
    });
</script>
```

But when I do this it doesn't show me anything...

Do you have any idea about this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you check browser console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of this plugin, the `.popup()` method does not make the content appear but rather enables it as a popup upon page load.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/EC8WP/) a fiddle to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thank you it works. But I see that `my_modal_1_open` makes it work and `my_modal_open_1` doesn't work even if I add : `$(".my_modal_open_1").click(function() {` I don't understand this...

Comment: The `_open` part of the class name is a special suffix used by the plugin to identify the element as a popup opener. Essentially what the plugin does is look for any elements with the class name format `popupclassname_open`. Then whenever that element is clicked, it will open the popup element with the class name `popupclassname`. There's no need for you to write `$("popupclassname_open").click(function() {` because the plugin does this for you.

Comment: The same idea also applies to any element with the class name suffix `_close`.

Answer (score 0):

Before any jQuery is readen, you need to type `$(document).ready(function)({
 //all jQuery codes goes here
});`
In your case should be:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function)({
        //then goes what you wanted to do
        $(".my_modal_open_1").click(function() {
           $("#my_modal_1").popup();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try the suggestion from Sashka. And if that does not work try to put an alert inside the onclick function to see if it gets executed.

You can also try:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#my_modal_1").popup();
    });
</script>
```

To see if the popup function works.